# How to modify Text widget in Tkinter for interlinear anotation

Tags: python, tkinter

I was wondering if it is possible to create a textbox with tkinter that can handle interlinear input. I need to be able to have different lines "connected" to each other, and the behaviour of each line can be independent. Here is [an example](http://scholarspace.manoa.hawaii.edu/bitstream/handle/10125/1725/robinson7.jpg). It is from a linguistic annotation program. The idea is that if I have a line, say:

```
this    is      an       example
x.Det   be.V    a.Det    example.N
```

The spacing of the first line is automatically adjusted some line is modified to allow enough space for each word in the second line to not overlap with the words in the first line.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you wanting the user to be able to edit the text, or simply display the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to use a fixed width font (such as courrier) in which all characters are the same width, then format it as pure text by padding with spaces.

[image: Example output]

```
from Tkinter import *

sentence = [ 'this', 'is', 'an', 'example' ]
result   = [ 'x.Det', 'be.V', 'a.Det', 'example.N' ]

line_start = [0, len(sentence)] # Used to split the sentence into lines no longer than line_len
line_len = 20 # Max characters in each line, including extra spaces
segment_len = 0

for i in range(len(sentence)):
    s_len = len(sentence[i])
    r_len = len(result[i])

    # Pad words (or word groups) so the segments of sentence and result have the same width
    if s_len > r_len:
        result[i] += ' ' * s_len - r_len
    elif s_len < r_len:
        sentence[i] += ' ' * (r_len - s_len)

    segment_len += max(r_len, s_len) + 1

    # Check the line length
    if segment_len > line_len:
        segment_len = 0
        line_start.insert(1, i)

root = Tk()

for i in range(len(line_start)-1):
    sentence_segment = ' '.join( sentence[line_start[i]:line_start[i+1]] )
    ts = Text(root, font='TkFixedFont', width = line_len, height = 1)
    ts.insert(END, sentence_segment)
    ts.pack()

    result_segment = ' '.join( result[line_start[i]:line_start[i+1]] )
    tr = Text(root, font='TkFixedFont', width = line_len, height = 1, foreground='grey')
    tr.insert(END, result_segment)
    tr.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Another way is to use a single tab, then use tags to configure the tabstops for each pair of lines.

Comment: Bryan - could you make that work for a variable font? How would you know where to put the tab stops if you did?

Comment: Yes, you could make it work for a variable font. It will likely take a bit of work, but it can be done. Tkinter gives you a way to determine the length of a string in a given font. So, you can measure each word or phrase, and then set each tabstop accordingly.

Comment: I need it to be automatic as the user writes. Say the user wrote:
'word1 word2' in the first line, and then, in the second line he starts a word that is longer than the first 'longword', the program should automatically align it. Also, the user shouldn't be able to change the alignment. I don't know if it might be easier to draw a new widget in qt or something like that.

Comment: I wondered if that was what you wanted. Since the processing for short-ish amounts of text is fairly quick, you could try this: Listen for key-strokes. When the user presses a key which defines the end of a word, regenerate the user interface and set the cursor back where it should be. It's not elegant, but it should work, at least for a lab application (which I imagine this is). Alternatively, you could have a text area (which allows nice formatting etc) and a feedback area which repeats the text and analysis, nicely formatted, in a read-only area.

Comment: Moving still further from the spec, I once toyed with the idea of a UI for machine translation in which the user could select a region and right-click a list of alternative translations; in your case, you could create a dynamic 'right click' menu providing your feedback, perhaps copying it into a paste buffer if you select the menu item.